# Does normal javascript works on node - webkit or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used normal javascript in **node - webkit** for eg:

```
var blinkOrder = 20;
var blinkNumber = 12;
var asdf = document.title;
function asd(){
    if (blinkNumber >= blinkOrder) {
        document.title = ' hi';
        blinkNumber = 0;
    }
    else{
        document.title = asdf;
        blinkNumber++;
    }
    setTimeout(asd(),10000);
}
asd();
```

And I am getting error Like this:

> **Uncaught** node.js **Error** *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*
>    at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index‌​.html:5:13)
>    at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index‌​.html:14:13) at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index‌​.html:14:13)

Comment: The error stems from the the fact where `asd` is a string containing `document.title`.

Comment: although i changed `asd = document.title` to `asdf = document.title` i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, normal Javascript works on Node webkit.

Node runs a Javascript V8 engine, so any JS function will be understood in Node.

Your error is the following :

```
var asd = document.title; //This is a string

setTimeout(asd(),1000); //You call asd as a function, which does not exist, hence the error
```

EDIT :

With the new variable name, that should work :

```
var blinkOrder = 20;
var blinkNumber = 12;
var asdf = document.title;
function asd(){
    if (blinkNumber >= blinkOrder) {
        document.title = ' hi';
        blinkNumber = 0;
    }
    else{
        document.title = asdf;
        blinkNumber++;
        setTimeout(asd(),1000);
    }
}
asd();
```

Comment: i corrected that... changed _var asd_ to **asdf** then again I am getting  error like this: >Uncaught node.js Error 

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index.html:5:13)
    at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index.html:14:13)
    at asd (file:///C:/Users/Humlal/Downloads/Compressed/node-webkit-v0.10.5-win-ia32/index.html:14:13)

Comment: the function `setTimeout(reference, time_in_ms)` expects a reference, and you are giving the result of the asd() function, and so you are indefinitely recursively invoking the asd() function.

Comment: @laruiss http://thecodelesscode.com/case/9

Comment: Actually, with that code, there will still be a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at asd` ;-)

Comment: true, but it'll happen later :-D, corrected (although I do not see the point of this piece of code)

Comment: I really don't understand i tried changing the variable name too but still I am getting the same error...

Comment: the setTimeout will fire indefinitely. Look at my example, if you set it within the else clause, it'll fire only until your condition is met, then stop and everything will be fine :-)

Comment: @BibashAdhikari `setTimeout(asd(),1000);` should be `setTimeout(asd,1000);`. In your original code, you are *calling* `asd`, but you should be *only* passing in the *reference* to the function `asd`. Subtle, but very important difference.

Comment: @SalehenRahman i have been using setTimeout as setTimeout('functionName();',ms)... isn't that the way to use it?

Comment: @BibashAdhikari [that is a terrible way to use it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21). You're essentially doing an eval call, which you shouldn't do.

Comment: By "you shouldn't do", I mean that you should not be doing for just any pieces of code. Your use case could simply be done inside a separate callback, not inside a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I understand the downvotes, I would like to add this answer :

Be careful with hoisting (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)!

Functions and variables are hoisted, but functions take precedence is JS in hoisting, so `asd`, in your code, is first assigned the function, and then the document.title value.

```
console.log(asd); // asd(), because even if the function is defined further
                  // in the code, it is hoisted
var asd = document.title;
console.log(asd); // document.title value, so the string of the page title
function asd(){
    if (blinkNumber >= blinkOrder) {
        document.title = ' hi';
        blinkNumber = 0;
    }
    else{
        document.title = asd; // Why ??!?!
        blinkNumber++;
    }
    setTimeout(asd(),1000); // setTimeout() is expecting a function reference!
}
asd(); // Here, asd has been assigned the document.title value, and a string, not being a function, cannot be invoked, thus the error thrown.
```

Comment: OP has corrected his code, but not his post, check comments to my answer. (and WTF is not constructive criticism)

Comment: @xShirase you are right, corrected my answer